# Exposing Firebase Keys to the internet

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I am storing something in Firebase and the key of that is something like `-L1gMGVKaj-qU8O05eeT`, is it safe to create public URLs like `http://example.com/item/-L1gMGVKaj-qU8O05eeT`?

Is it safe to distribute internal push keys to public, provided that proper database rules are in place?

Answer (score 2):

There is no security issue in using push ids/keys in public URLs provided that your credentials (e.g. Server Keys or Service Accounts etc) are safe and not viewable.
However if you want that users should not be able to guess other push ids/keys then you should check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43130258/9152999)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your url using the keys generated by firebase on basis of timestamp. But it will not be user friendly. you can convert the key to unix timestamp and then use it for url. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908312/can-you-get-the-timestamp-from-a-firebase-array-key)